# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates

I update/insert values in a single table with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` function. So far everything is fine.

```
INSERT INTO table1 SET field1=aa, field2=bb, field3=cc
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET field1=aa, field2=bb, field3=cc;
```

But now I would like to achieve that the update only is done if a condition (`WHERE`) is true.

Syntactically not correct:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SET field1=aa, field2=bb, field3=cc
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET field1=aa, field2=bb, field3=cc WHERE field4=zz;
```

Any ideas how the correct SQL statement is?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Using IF() should work, though it's not nice:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SET 
 field1=aa, 
 field2=bb, 
 field3=cc 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET 
 field1 = IF( field4 = zz, aa, field1 ),
 field2 = IF( field4 = zz, bb, field2 ),
 field3 = IF( field4 = zz, cc, field3 )
```

Only update the fields with new values if the condition is met, otherwise keep the old ones.