# MySQL WHERE issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting an issue with following query:

```
INSERT INTO guess (user_id, logo_id, guess, level) VALUES (:user_id,:logo_id,:guess,:level) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE guess_count = guess_count + 1 WHERE guessed=0
```

I haven't been using SQL for a while so it's a little rusty. The error indicates an error near `WHERE guessed=0`. The idea is that it only updates the `guess_count` when `guessed = 0`.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't find it...

(I'm using PDO, but that doesn't matter for SQL errors)

Comment: Regarding using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with `WHERE`, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982884/on-duplicate-key-update-with-where-condition

Comment: That works! Seems a bit stupid if you have multiple fields needing to be updated upon that one variable - luckily I only have one!

Comment: Use: `...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE guess_count = CASE WHEN guessed = 0 THEN guess_count + 1 ELSE guess_count END ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer given by [showdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924299/showdev) is here: [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982884/on-duplicate-key-update-with-where-condition)

In short: use `IF(condition, true, false)` instead of `WHERE condition`.